# Pass variable name as module argument in SAS/IML

Tags: sas

In SAS/IML I'm trying to build a module that prints the name of an input parameter.

The following pseudo-code describes what I want to do:

```
START return_name (input_parameter);
    PRINT <the name of input_parameter>;
FINISH return_name;
```

Then with:

```
RUN return_name (some_var);
```

I receive output:

```
some_var
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not possible in SAS/IML 9.3 because there is no function at 9.3 that interrogates the symbol table of the parent environment.

However, in SAS/IML 13.1 (released with SAS 9.4m1), you can use the [PARENTNAME function](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/imlug/66845/HTML/default/viewer.htm#imlug%5flangref%5fsect301.htm) to do this. Inside the modules use

> name = ParentName("input_parameter");  PRINT name;